# Mongoose query returning only 101 records

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I had a Mongoose query returning JSON of users:

```
var query = Users.find({})
query.exec(function(err, users){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
    res.json(users);
});
```

It didn't work - the request failed after 2 minutes with no error. I added .limit() to the query, and I found that only 101 records can be returned from MongoDB. So I increased the batch size of the query:

```
var query = Users.find({}).batchSize(1000000);
query.exec(function(err, users){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
    res.json(users);
});
```

and now it works. However I guess that increasing the batch size is not a desired solution, and that I should use cursors or streams to make it work in a proper way. How should I proceed with it to have all the data saved to JSON and returned by the GET request?

Comment: Could you post the code that returned the 101 records?

Comment: Just added .limit(101) to the query, .limit(102) resulted in query failure, To make it clear:

`Users.find({})` - query failure after 2 minutes with no error or information from the server; `Users.find({}).limit(102)` - query failure after 2 minutes with no error or information from the server; `Users.find({}).limit(101)` - 101 records returned; `Users.find({}).batchSize(1000000)` - all records returned

Comment: look on this question, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643195/mongoose-limiting-query-to-1000-results-when-i-want-more-all-migrating-from-2-6

Comment: Mongoose's find is an asynchronous function and you are likely existing your application before it has finished streaming all the data.

Comment: Asynchronous call is for sure not the case here. I call the GET method directly from the browser, there is no more logic, just one function returning the JSON.

Comment: If you're calling the GET method directly from browser, then it's likely that the browser request is just timing out after 2 mins. That's why you're not getting errors from Mongoose

Comment: Ok, but the timeout is not the case here either. Returning all of these records takes less than 100ms when I increase the batch size to 1000000. The problem I'm trying to solve is that mongoDB returns data in chunks (101 records each), and you have to explicitly ask for the next batch, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's fair, I was just pointing out why you were getting no errors. Seeing as you mentioned streams earlier, have you tried: `Users.find({}).stream().pipe(res);` ?

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work either - when I use stream, 101 records are returned immediately, and then request is still going, but next records are never returned. It eventually times out, and you are left with JSON with 101 records only.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the other thread, upgraded mongoose to 4.3.7 and now it works!