# mongoose find stuck above 101 item returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When trying to fetch all entry of a collection, the command find seemed to stay stuck an infinite amout of time (the callbacks are never called). I tried to limit the number of entries returned and that worked, but only when limiting to 101 or less. When i try to limit it to 102 or more, the command stays stuck.

For example :

```
User.find().limit(101).exec()  //works
User.find().limit(90).exec()   //works
User.find().limit(105).exec()  //doesn't work
User.find().exec()             //doesn't work
```

I don't think this problem happended before today. What can be the cause?

Comment: is an error being thrown?  For example, what would this output if anything?  User.find().exec(function(err,cb) { if (err) {throw err} })

Comment: nothing. No error, no result. The command seems to be frozen forever

Comment: Looks pretty similar to [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012463/mongoose-query-returning-only-101-records). Have you updated mongoose to the latest version? I'm not able to reproduce the problem with 4.3.7.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092234/node-js-mongoose-find-freezes-node-when-more-than-100-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use batchSize(value),
like

```
User
    .find()
    .batchSize(999999)
    .limit(105)
    .exec();
```