# Node.js + mongoose find freezes node when more than 100 results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple mongoose model on which I call find with limit max 100 it calls the done callback:

```
this.find({}).limit(100).exec(done);
```

The callback is never called If I modify this line into (or any higher number)

```
this.find({}).limit(101).exec(done);
```

There is no error anywhere, the database keeps working, but this node app freezes and must be restarted.

If I ssh into the server to connect to the same database and connect to mongo shell, on the same collection find({}) returns all ~700 collections in less than a sec.
When I cloned the same database to my local PC and run the app to connect to local database it worked, but the app freezes on the server if its connect to the database on the same server.

Any idea how to debug this one?

Edit1: Added model file:

Model file:

```
'use strict';

let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let foodSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: Object,
        type: String,
        description: Object,
        price: Number,
        priceBig: Number,
        active: Boolean
    },
    {
        collection: 'foods'
    }
);

let model = mongoose.model('food', foodSchema);

model.getAllFoods = function (done) {
    this.find({}, done);
};

model.getActiveFoods = function (done) {
    this.find({active: true}, done);
};

model.getFoodById = function (id, done) {
    this.findOne({_id: id}, done);
};

module.exports = model;
```

Usage:

```
foodModel.getAllFoods(function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }

    res.send(docs);
});
```

getActiveFoods works just fine (returns 96 docs)

Comment: post your model file

Comment: Added and also an example how I use it. I'd use it without limit, but I was experimenting where it goes wrong and found out this behavior

Comment: There's been two other similar question over the last couple of days that didn't get resolved. What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: I was using 4.1.11 until now, I quickly checked with latest (4.3.7) and it seems ok. I'll do a complete check and report back if updating solved this, thanks for the tip.
Weird that it worked at local but not on the server

Comment: shouldn't you be using `return next();`?

Comment: Its clear that there is an error and its getting hung up because you arent using `return next(err);`

Comment: The callback of find is never invoked, so it doesn't matter what I have there. Besides the logic I have is what I need - if there is an error during the database call I want to send a 500 status otherwise send the documents.

Comment: @wrleskovec there isn't a `next()`. `res.sendStatus(500)` is the end of the server request. They have `return;` following it, which would be no different than `return res.sendStatus(500)`. In either case, the return statement in the error block prevents any following code from executing.  If that were the issue, they would be getting a "can't set headers after they've been sent" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the tip from JohnnyK I updated Mongoose from 4.1.11 to 4.3.7 and that fixed the issue.